# Flashback to the 70s: first tcp implementations from Cerf, Kahn and Tomlinson - why a retransmission flag bit was never considered?

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols

I am currently delving some of the internals of the first TCP implementations, reading the following:

- 1974 - Cerf, Kahn - A Protocol for Packet Network Intercommunication
- 1975 - Tomlinson - Selecting Sequence Numbers

However, both papers present the problem (and relative management) of retransmission vs legal transmission with same sequence numbers.

The first paper, for example, restricts the legal sequence numbers with a window of less than n/2, where n is the maximum sequence number.
The second paper, increasing the elegance, puts some restrictions on choosing the correct sequence number upon the SYN phase to distinguish from late packets and correct ones.

However, I am wondering why they never considered adding a flag bit to report a retransmission to the receiver... they implemented some strategies to inference that there was a retransmission, however, such a flag wouldn't have simplified the things? Surely there are valid reasons that suggest this idea as useless, but however, is there any clue if they ever rejected this and why?

Thanks, D.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is designed to tolerate both duplicated and out of order segments, so the flag to report a retransmission simply will not solve both of those issues.

For instance, receiver might get a segment with a retransmission flag set and later the same segment without the flag (out of order delivery). Will it help? I guess, the logic to detect duplicates/out of order delivery still will be needed...

Comment: Hi Andriy, thanks. Surely, the flag bit would not help the out of order delivery. However, that one is managed through sequence numbers, that point to the right place of the receiving buffer. In your example, the two segments would be duplicates, not out of order, as the sequence number would be the same. Anyway, thinking at the duplication issue, I have made this other thoughs: - maybe, if a small amount of retransmissions are expected, a flag bit would be an undesirable overhead - moreover, that flag would be useful in the original proposal of C&K, but not in that of tomlinson

Comment: in C&K it would have permitted a window bigger than n/2. However, in tomlinson proposal, the sequence number selection logic would make that flag useless, as that logic is used just for coping with duplication. Supposing same segment transmitted (A) and retransmitted (B) after timeout. Then if: - A arrives first than B: A is not current and B should be used instead. In this case "my" flag would have been useless, as it would be present in B only. On the contrary the 3-way handshake manages this case perfectly. - B arrives before A, B is current and should be accepted. In this case, probably,

Comment: the "flag" would be just a useless information to the receiver, that anyway has the most current segment. Maybe, the answer to my question would be just that tomlinson proposal managed the retransmission problem with elegance without the need for an extra bit of overhead? Thanks again